# What are accessor and mutator methods in Scala?

Tags: scala

These are apparently generated in scala automatically for any parameters in constructors (which I suppose also implies that they can be added manually somewhere else) but what are these things?

Comment: Check http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html section "Accesors/Mutators" to see what they talk about.

Comment: Basically accessor = getter / mutator = setter... give or take.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Accessor and mutator methods are normal methods with special names. Look at the following example:

```
class A {
  var x: Int = _
}
```

Is the same as (as in "the compiler generates the following"):

```
class A {
  private[this] var internal: Int = _
  // this is the accessor
  def x: Int = internal 
  // this is the mutator
  def x_=(x: Int): Unit = internal = x
}
```

When you write or read `x`, the following happens:

```
val a: A = ???
println(a.x) // -> method x on A is called
a.x = 1 // syntactic sugar for a.x_=(1)
```

The nice thing about this is, that you can change a `var` at a later point in time to include, say, consistency checks:

```
class A {
  private[this] var _x: Int = _
  def x: Int = _x 
  def x_=(x: Int): Unit = {
    if (x < 0)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must be non-negative")
    _x = x
  }
}
```

The ability to replace variables by accessors/mutators transparently is also known as [uniform access principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_access_principle).

Comment: Are you sure that your statement "the compiler generates the following" is true? AfaIk, these additional methods are only generated if you define a class like `class A (var x: Int) { }`. I speculate that in your example `class A { var x: Int = _ }` the member variable `x` is accessed/mutated _directly_ w/o additional method invocations.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. IIRC, they are not generated for members that are `private[this]`.